# Image appears half Latex EPS Photoshop/Gimp

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps

This is the first time this is happening in years of latex usage.

I recently started using photoshop, and having exported the image in a variety of formats in photoshop (pdf/jpeg/png) and subsequently convert that to eps on Gimp (my latex document is set for eps usage, I don't want to change that for various reasons).

When I compile latex (latex-->to dvi --> to pdf) only half the image appears.

All my other images done the same way work fine. I don't know why. Did anyone encounter this? The images are uploaded here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3dwKaPZX2EnSV9XYWJuSGFoNTg&usp=sharing

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: ooh this sounds like a Sherlock Holmes novel! `:)` Do you have any problematic (`.png`, `.eps`) sample combo we could take a look?

Comment: I do, if only I could find the upload facility...

Comment: Why the detour via Gimp, Photoshop can save as EPS.

Comment: I used the EPS facility in photoshop and converted pdf-EPS via Gimp too. Both don't work.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't upload eps files to this site. However, if you can make the file available for download you can add a link here. I expect that the problem is caused by a bad bounding box, but won't know for sure until I see the file.

Comment: @IanThompson Well, can you describe how a bad bounding box looks like?

Comment: So these are the images (photoshop, saved in jpg then converted with gimp to EPS).  https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B3dwKaPZX2EnSV9XYWJuSGFoNTg&usp=sharing

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the `eps` file. Can you add an example latex code to your question so that the problem can be reproduced? (I tried with a basic document and the whole image appeared).